# What does the little arrow mean between two segments of a Quadrilateral

Tags: notation, angle, quadrilateral

in the below image, what does the little arrow between AD and BC mean?
[image: Please click to see the image]

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that the line segment $\overline{AD}$ is parallel to the line segment $\overline{BC}$.

Comment: It seems to mean «parallel». I have never seen this notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Guessed so too, but wasn't sure